# Dimensional Modelling for boolean OR filtering

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimension, dimensional-modeling

How does dimensional modeling address Boolean-OR filtering requirements?

For example, assume a dimension `Customer` with attributes `HomeAddressId` and `BillingAddressId`. Both fields point into an `Address` dimension.  Some business users will only care about home address, others will only care about billing address, but some users want to filter results to, for example, "all customers with billing or home address in Texas".

Another example: a 'Contact' dimension may have attributes `Email1` and `Email2`, but filtering will almost always be on both fields rather than one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

**Alias-based Approach**

In this approach, `Address` dimension table will be aliased as `HomeAddress` and `BillAddress` and the `ID` from both of these two tables will be linked to `HomeAddressId` and `BillingAddressId` columns of `Customer` table respectively. In this design pattern, when you ask a question like this,

> all customers with billing or home address in Texas

It will translate to a query like this:

```
SELECT Customer.*
FROM Customer
LEFT OUTER JOIN Address HomeAddress ON Customer.HomeAddressId    = HomeAddress.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Address BillAddress ON Customer.BillingAddressId = BillAddress.Id
WHERE HomeAddress.Name = 'Texas' OR BillAddress.Name = 'Texas'
```

The Aliases will be defined ideally in the Reporting layer (e.g. `Universe` in *SAP Business Objects*) or query layer.

**Bridge Table Approach**

In this approach, you will create a new bridge table to store the relation between `Customer` and `Address` according to the types. This approach is not "dimensional" approach as such but can be used in dimensional modeling in the form of *Fact-less Fact table*.

```
CustomerID   |  Type  | AddressID
-----------------------------------
1            |  Home  | 10
2            |  Home  | 20
2            |  Bill  | 30
3            |  Home  | 10
3            |  Bill  | 40
```

The query in this approach will take the form,

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer.*
FROM Customer, CustomerAddress, Address
WHERE Customer.ID  = CustomerAddress.CustomerID
AND   Address.ID   = CustomerAddress.AddressID
AND   Address.Name = 'Texas'
```

This approach is more applicable in cases where you need to analyze relation between customers belonging to same address.

Not sure if you were looking for this exactly, but hope the answer will be helpful for your visualization and design.